# $G_m$-cohomology of a motif (that corresponds to a stack?)

Tags: motives, stacks, cohomology, picard-group, ag.algebraic-geometry

As in the question [For a G-variety, what could one say about the motif of the corresponding simplicial variety](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/52426/for-a-g-variety-one-could-one-say-about-the-motif-of-the-corresponding-simplicia/52472#52472)
I am in the following situation: $G$ is an algerbraic group, and X is a smooth $G$-variety. Then the  simlicial variety whose terms are $G^i\times X$ yields a 'complex of varieties' $\dots\to G\times G\times X\to G\times X\to X$; next I obtain a Voevodsky's motivic complex $C$.

Next, I want to compute the (Zariski) cohomology of $C$ with coefficients in $G_m$. How could one do this? David Ben-Zvi wrote that this is the motif of the stack $X/G$. I don't know anything about stacks, so I would like to know whether this helps. For example, can one prove that $H^2(C,G_m)$ vanishes?